# How do i select an element from a google drop down in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have a field where it picks the location from a dropdown which is from google dropdown and not a native dropdown. So how can i click on that element in dropdown using selenium.

Comment: Could you share an example website or relevant html? Also, what all have you tried.

Comment: <input type="text" id="locationGoogle" required="" class="form-control input-home-search user-success" placeholder="
Search property for rent by locality
" name="locationGoogle" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Pick a area where you need the property')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" data-source="" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1">

Comment: example:Nobroker.in , trying to click an item from search property field.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you provided in the comments. This way users will understand your question better !

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: am using Java as the language

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The results are show in an HTML div. The only reason why you are not able to find this div in HTML is because it appears somewhere near the bottom of the HTML and it is fragile enough to get dismissed with a click anywhere.

Coming to the code, your search results are generated inside individual divs with id="pac-item". So you have to just find them and click which ever item you want. Please don't forget to mark the answer

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.nobroker.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("locationGoogle")).sendKeys("n");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item"));

    for(WebElement element : elements)
    {
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
        if(element.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Sopara"))
        {
            element.click();
        }
    }
```

Of course you will update the code to make it more efficient.